# SingleChildScrollView not working in webpage

Tags: flutter

Am developing a webpage and `SingleChildScrllView` isn't allowing me to scroll and resulting in overflowing pixels when content exceeds the height.

I also tried wrapping it inside an Expanded (saw this on stcakoverflow) but it makes only the content in my case column scrollable, instead of whole page. I also tried wrapping singleChildScroll and Column in a container but this also causes overflowing pixels.

**code:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeMobile extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = 'mobile_home.dart';
  const HomeMobile({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeMobile> createState() => _HomeMobileState();
}

class _HomeMobileState extends State<HomeMobile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.tealAccent,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.tealAccent,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.tealAccent,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.teal,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution. Needed to wrap `singlechildscrollview` inside a container while giving it width of screen width.